# How can I set a certain time to make the notification show up in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I made a web view app at android studio with Kotlin. I want to make it show a notification at a certain time. For example if it's 1:00pm, the app would tell me to eat lunch. Would there be any functions I could use to set the time and make the notification show up? As a beginner, it would be good if you tell me a web page for studying kotlin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) & [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) to achieve what you expecting here.
For Kotlin, [this](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/01_introduction/01_Hello%20world) is a good start.

Comment: Most welcome. Please close your question by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer that helped you most.